# Echoing not leaving the page

Tags: php, email, subscription

I have a simple subscribe to newsletter form on my website. And I wanted you to help me make it more userfriendly.
what my form can not do:
-it can't Echo "success" "not success" NOT leaving the page(it shows status in a new page, which is frustrating)
-it can not validate correct and incorrect emails(if you put in some rubbish, I will receive it anyway)

these are the main problems of my form. Will you please direct me to some useful tuts, or just correct my codes. Any help will be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="subscribe">
          <form method="POST" action="subscribe.php">
<p><input type="text" name="Name" size="24" maxlength="40" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif" value="Ваше имя"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваше имя') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Ваше имя';}"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="Email" size="24" maxlength="40" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif" value="Ваш email"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваш email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Ваш email';}"></p>
<p><input type="image" value="submit" name="Submit" src="images/subscribe.png"></p>
</form>

        </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$recipient = "order@dastiche.kz";
$subject = "Subscriber";
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$location = "index.html";
$sender = $recipient;
$body .= "Name: ".$_REQUEST['Name']." \n";
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";


if (($name != "") or ($email != ""))
// Если существуют проверяем... 
{
   if ((strlen($name) >= 2) and (strlen($name) <= 25))
   {
   $name = stripslashes($name);
   $name = html_entity_decode($name);
   $name = strip_tags($name);
   }
   else
   {
   echo " something is wrong with name field ";
   echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='get back'
   onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
   }

   if (eregi("^[._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[.a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-z]{2,6}$", $email))
   {
   $email = stripslashes($email);
   $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
   $email = strip_tags($email);
   }
   else
   {
   echo "There are some mistakes in the \"E-mail\" field";
   echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='try again'
   onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
   }

}
// Если не существуют выводим сообщение... 
else
{
echo "Please, fill in blanks";
echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='try again'
onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
}

   if (($name) and ($email))
{
   echo "thanks for subscription!";
}


mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
header( "Location: $location" );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok here is the code with validation u can add email functionality on your own. Also i didn't test this but hopefully it will work..

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if($uname == ''){
        $errors['uname'] = "Username is required.";
    }
    if($email == ''){
        $errors['email'] = "Email is required!";
    }
    if(empty($errors)){
        echo "Subscription Successfull";
    }else{
        echo "Subscription failed";
    }
}
  ?>
  <div id="error">
<ul>
<?php
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo "<li>".$error."</li>";
    }
?>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <form name="subscribe" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['uname'])? $_POST['uname']:'';?>"/>
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks Moax for your effort, but code doesnt seem to work. It echoes something like two empty boxes and submit button)

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dastiche/public_html/subscribe.php:53) in /home/dastiche/public_html/subscribe.php on line 58 - what does this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

It probably IS echoing but it happens so fast you likely don't see it before you redirect.  Try putting an `exit;` after the mail() function and before the header() function and I reckon you will see it.

WHat you would need to do is pause somehow between the echo and the redirection.  There are a number of ways you could do this using PHP or javascript.

**[EDIT]  Update on how to keep page loaded with echo**

```
       if (($name) and ($email))
{
   echo "thanks for subscription!";
}


mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
// comment out the redirection and you should send the email, 
// reload the page and have the "thanks" echoed.
// header( "Location: $location" );
```

But there is still a lot of room for improvement.  If we do it for you you won't learn much, but this should get you started

Comment: Thank you Steve, but I will slightly rephrase what I asked. I dont want users to be redirected. Just echo underneath the "submit" button success/fail and that is all. Could you help me with that? or do you know any step by step tuts, so that I could go and make it myself.

Comment: then remove the redirection code and put your php and form on same page it will save you a lot of heck./

Comment: Moax, I might be asking too much, but could you please show me it within code? I am not that good as coder, I am graphic designer:-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some suggestions to improve your code..
1. Use type of input field which will get email as email instead of text..
2. there mmust be an AND statement instead of OR since u want to execute form submition code only if the user provided name as well as email.

Comment: Thanks, Moax, I have already added your suggestions. But main problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

`subscribe.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
$recipient = "order@dastiche.kz";
$subject = "Subscriber";
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$location = "index.html";
$sender = $recipient;
$body .= "Name: ".$_RE``QUEST['Name']." \n";
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";


if (($name != "") or ($email != ""))
// Если существуют проверяем... 
{
if ((strlen($name) >= 2) and (strlen($name) <= 25))
{
$name = stripslashes($name);
$name = html_entity_decode($name);
$name = strip_tags($name);
}
else
{
echo " something is wrong with name field ";
echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='get back'
onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
}

if (eregi("^[._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[.a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-z]{2,6}$", $email))
{
$email = stripslashes($email);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$email = strip_tags($email);
}
else
{
echo "There are some mistakes in the \"E-mail\" field";
echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='try again'
onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
}

}
// Если не существуют выводим сообщение... 
else
{
echo "Please, fill in blanks";
echo "<center><input name='back' type='button' value='try again'
onclick= 'javascript:history.back()'></center>";
}

if (($name) and ($email))
{
echo "thanks for subscription!";
}


mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
header( "Location: $location" );
}
?>

 <div class="subscribe">
      <form method="POST" action="">
 <p><input type="text" name="Name" size="24" maxlength="40" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif" value="Ваше имя"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваше имя') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Ваше имя';}"></p>
 <p><input type="text" name="Email" size="24" maxlength="40" style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif" value="Ваш email"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваш email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Ваш email';}"></p>
 <p><input type="image" value="submit" name="Submit" src="images/subscribe.png"> </p>
 </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: It echoes my subscribe div with images and thats all.